# Excel VBA - Sheet Name Wild Card Search

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with lot of sheets and pivot tables. All the sheets with Pivot Tables have Pvt Tbl in the sheet name. Now I want to clear data in all the sheets except sheets with Pivot Table and Control Sheet (Where I have all my buttons for operations) I have the following code so far but it doesn't seem to be working. I also want make "Control" sheet only visible and rest of the sheets should be hidden. I am doing a wild card search in sheet names by using Like Statement with "*Pvt Tbl" but it still deletes Pivot Tables in all worksheets. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

```
Sub ClearData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not ws.Name Like "Control" Or ws.Name Like "*Pvt Tbl" Then ws.Cells.Delete: ws.Cells.Delete
    If Not ws.Name Like "Control" Then ws.Visible = False
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Think about the condition you're writing.

```
If Not ws.Name Like "Control" Or ws.Name Like "*Pvt Tbl"
```

*If the name is not Control OR the name ends with "Pvt Tbl", ...*

Sounds like you want the condition to instead be:

*If the name is not Control AND the name does not end with "Pvt Tbl", ...*

```
If Not ws.Name Like "Control" And Not ws.Name Like "*Pvt Tbl"
```

It's easy to forget that computers will always do exactly what you tell them to do.

This is one of the conditionals that might be more clear through the application of [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). A logically equivalent condition that might be easier to understand is:

```
If Not (ws.Name Like "Control" Or ws.Name Like "*Pvt Tbl")
```